# Как настроить ToggleButton для изменения текста?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Доброго дня!

Имеем: 6 Button, 1 ToggleButton, 1 TextView, и массив Array.
При нажатии одной из 6 кнопок, в TextView показывается информация.
Если перевести ToggleButton в значение true, при нажатии на эти же 6 кнопок будет выходит противоположная информация.
Все данные для TextView берутся из массива.

Теперь столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я нажимаю кнопку (например btnP) и в TextView выходит текст. После этого я нажимаю на ToggleButton и на экране ничего не происходит. Потом я снова нажимаю на эту же btnP и выводится другая информация.

Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии ToggleButton информация уже показанная в TextView сразу менялась на противоположную?

```
Bundle extraArray = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extraArray");
    ArrayList<Integer> Array = (ArrayList<Integer>) extraArray.getSerializable("Array");

    assert Array != null;
    TextView.setText(Array.get(1));
    iP = 1;
    iL = 3;
    iC = 5;
    iT = 7;
    iH = 9;
    iW = 11;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Bundle extraArray = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extraArray");
    ArrayList<Integer> Array = (ArrayList<Integer>) extraRunes.getSerializable("Array");

    assert Array != null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnP:
            TextView.setText(Array.get(iP));
            break;
        case R.id.btnL:
            TextView.setText(Array.get(iL));
            break;
        case R.id.btnC:
            TextView.setText(Array.get(iC));
            break;
        case R.id.btnT:
            TextView.setText(Array.get(iT));
            break;
        case R.id.btnH:
            TextView.setText(Array.get(iH));
            break;
        case R.id.btnW:
            TextView.setText(Array.get(iW));
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    boolean checked = tbFlip.isChecked();
    Bundle extraArray = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extraArray");
    ArrayList<Integer> Array = (ArrayList<Integer>) extraRunes.getSerializable("Array");

    if (checked) {
        assert Array != null;
        iP = 2;
        iL = 4;
        iC = 6;
        iT = 8;
        iH = 10;
        iW = 12;

    } else {
        assert Array != null;
        iP = 1;
        iL = 3;
        iC = 5;
        iT = 7;
        iH = 9;
        iW = 11;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При клике вам нужно запоминать, какая кнопка была нажата и в `onCheckedChanged` самостоятельно устанавливать изменённый текст в `TextView` в соответствии с нажатой ранее кнопкой.

Плюс, переписал немного ваш код:

```
// Глобальные переменные
private static final int iP = 1;
private static final int iL = 3;
private static final int iC = 5;
private static final int iT = 7;
private static final int iH = 9;
private static final int iW = 11;
private List<Integer> Array;
private int clickedButtonIndex = iP;
private int checked = 0;

// Видимо внутри onCreate
Array = (List<Integer>) extraRunes.getSerializable("Array");
assert Array != null;
setText();

@Override
public void onClick (View v){

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnP:
            clickedButtonIndex = iP;
            break;
        case R.id.btnL:
            clickedButtonIndex = iL;
            break;
        case R.id.btnC:
            clickedButtonIndex = iC;
            break;
        case R.id.btnT:
            clickedButtonIndex = iT;
            break;
        case R.id.btnH:
            clickedButtonIndex = iH;
            break;
        case R.id.btnW:
            clickedButtonIndex = iW;
            break;
    }

    setText();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked){
    checked = tbFlip.isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
    setText();
}

private void setText() {
    TextView.setText(Array.get(clickedButtonIndex + checked));
}
```

Только в Java принято имена переменным давать с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что массив так же можно объявить в глобальных переменных? И если Вам не сложно объяснить мне, я читал но не мог понять, зачем переменные объявлять приватными и публичными. Или дайте ссылку на полезный ресурс где бы я мог об этом узнать. Спасибо!

P.S. по логике этого кода, мне кажется Вы решили мою проблему. Сейчас опробую.

Comment: Да, массив уже объявлен глобальным для данного класса. Сделано это для того, чтобы присвоить ему значение всего один раз, а не каждый раз, когда он нужен в разных методах данного класса. По поводу [модификаторов доступа в Java](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.3.php)